# convert fully connected layer to conv2d and predict output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, densenet

I'm trying get flatten layer as input to convd2d and predicting the output for 10 class classification problem on Densenet with cifar-10 dataset.
following code snippet where I'm getting the error.

```
global compression
    BatchNorm = layers.BatchNormalization()(input)
    relu = layers.Activation('relu')(BatchNorm)
    AvgPooling = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(relu)
    flat = layers.Flatten()(AvgPooling)
    # output = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(flat)
    output = layers.Conv2D(filters=10,kernel_size=3,strides=1,activation='softmax',padding='valid')(flat)
```

I'm getting the following error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_513: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you flatten the data before the 2D convolution? It is normally the other way around. For Conv2D you need a 2D input and the flattening layer converts 2D to 1D.

Answer (score -1):

```
output = layers.Conv2D(filters=10, kernel_size=(1,1),strides =(2,2))
```

This code will change your dense layer to respective Conv2D layer. But to avoid any error you need to add `softmax` as different layer. Which should look like this:

```
not_final = layers.Activation('softmax')(output)

result = layers.Flatten()(not_final)
```